# Fast async way to check if file existin nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

I have used the following async method to check if file exists:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.exists = function(path, cb) {

  fs.stat(require('path').join(__dirname, '../public', path), function(err, stat) {
    if (err == null) {
      console.log('File exists :' + path);
      cb(true);
    } else if (err.code == 'ENOENT') {
      //file does not exist
      console.log('No file: ' + path);
      cb(false);
    } else {
      console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
      cb(false);
    }
  });

}
```

If file exists, i redirect to the file in pathStr. If not, display that resource does not exist. Although this is asynchronous, i notice that the web server is much slower and accepts fewer requests with this fs.stat method(if this is commented out, the performance is significantly better). Is there a way in node.js to speed up file exists or not check asynchronously ?

Comment: Checking synchronously would probably even be slower. I think the only way you can speed this up (from Node) is by caching the results (although this may not be possible if the number of files changes frequently; if only _new_ files are added, you can at least cache the positive, _"file exists"_, results). If your hardware is slow, Node can't help you.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks.The goal is to serve a large (downloaded  from somewhere) html file from the /public directory but sometimes it may have been deleted. So before redirecting to the file, we check whether it exists. Using node streams will help?Can we use XMLHttpRequest array buffers to initiate this request?What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Streams won't help. I do wonder if the bottleneck of checking for file existence is _that_ large, a quick benchmark tells me that I can easily run 25K `fs.stat` calls a second, on a slow server.

Comment: @robertklep hi,yes, you're right.i think the slow down was the result of network slowness,other servers we were connecting to being slow.sorry about that.although,i am still looking for a way to send large html files as response.

Comment: If you're using Express, you can use [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) to send large files (of any type).